# Swift / How to populate UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, swift

I have a controller with a Table View on it. Have defined my cells in a view and then I bind it to the table view. (Please excuse the terminology). App builds and runs fine but none of the labels defined in the cell show anything. Entire table is blank except for the cell separators. I've followed numerous tutorials and searched SO extensively for reasons, how to create ([Create a Table View - Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson7.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH8-SW1)), settings to check, all with the same results. I've also tried cleaning, restarting Xcode, etc. This is Xcode 8/Swift 3.

The view controller has a table view and I register the cell class like so in the viewDidLoad

```
self.tableView.registerCellClass(MenuTableViewCell.self)
```

UITableViewDataSource code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return menusItems.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MenuTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MenuTableViewCell

    let item = menusItems[indexPath.row]
    cell.setData(item)
    return cell
}
```

menuItems is an array of a struct I have that is created before anything else is done

BaseTableViewCell

```
open class BaseTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
class var identifier: String { return String.className(self) }

public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
}

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    setup()
}

open override func awakeFromNib() {
}

open func setup() {
}

open override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

open class func height() -> CGFloat {
    return 48
}

open func setData(_ data: Any?) {
    if let menuText = data as? String {
        self.textLabel?.text = menuText
    }
    if let menuImage = data as? UIImage {
        self.imageView?.image = menuImage
    }
}
}
```

Table View Cell code - inherits the BaseTableViewCell

```
class MenuTableViewCell: BaseTableViewCell {

//MARK: Properties
@IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var icon: UIImageView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

override func setData(_ data: Any?) {
    if let data = data as? MenuTableViewCellData {
        NSLog("menu name - %@", data.text)
        self.icon?.image = data.image
        self.name?.text = data.text
    }
}
}
```

All menu names are written to the debug area so the code is being executed.

I don't know if there is hook that is missing or if something else. Please let me know if anything further is also needed. Any help is appreciated.

Screenshots showing IBOutlets connected
[image: name]

[image: icon]

Here is the delegate and data source from the controller

```
extension LeftViewController : UITableViewDelegate {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return MenuTableViewCell.height()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let menu = LeftMenu(rawValue: indexPath.row) {
        self.changeViewController(menu)
    }
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if self.tableView == scrollView {

    }
}
}

extension LeftViewController : UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return menusItems.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MenuTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MenuTableViewCell

    let item = menusItems[indexPath.row]
    cell.setData(item)
    return cell
}
}
```

Thanks everyone for your help. I was able to get it working. I removed the XIB file, created the layout in the view and then wired it up from there (followed [here](http://www.apptuitions.com/uitableview-with-custom-cell-in-swift/) for how to).

Comment: where call you the menuItems? Post your code

Comment: did you wire the outlets using interface builder?

Comment: @MatiasElorriaga I did.

Comment: where did you design your `MenuTableViewCell`, storyboard or nib? If you have designed your cell in a nib file then try registering nib to the tableView instead of the class.

Comment: Have you tried using the view debugger? Perhaps it will show your cell constraints are wrong, or the text alpha is zero, or some other view is covering the cell's content view.

Comment: @GrahamPerks Just looked at the view debugger. I show 2 layers. 1 is the UITableViewWrapperView and above it is the UITableViewCellContentView. Nothing about that

Comment: Nothing in the content view? That should contain the name label and your icon... I think you have a clue here. Have you configured the auto-layout constraints for these views?

Comment: There is no constraints on the label and icon. There are constraints on the View Controller scenes View which is where this is used. I'm following https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift and am trying to place an image in the left navigation slide controller. I should had mentioned this much sooner. My apologies.

Answer (score 3):

Verify that you've connected the `IBOutlets` for `name` and `icon` in `MenuTableViewCell`.  Assuming what you say is true, that the `NSLog` in `setData` is called, chances are you haven't connected the `IBOutlets` for the table view cell subclass.

Comment: I just checked the Connections Inspector and it shows the reference outlets for the name and icon

Comment: Screen shots added.

Answer (score 1):

You may have 0-height rows. I see a `height` method in there - what is calling it? Do you have an implementation of

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
```

somewhere?

Are you setting the table view's `rowHeight`?

Comment: Yes. The delegate returns the row height from return MenuTableViewCell.height() which inherits from BaseTableViewCell which has the height defined as 48

Answer (score -1):

Can you check whether name and icon have proper constraints

Comment: How do I do that? name and icon were created from just the drag and drop from the object library. The attributes are all the defaults